# Как залить голосовое сообщение в виде сущности в БД?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, sqlalchemy

Пишу бота в телеграмме на Aiogram/Python
Задумка в том что бы ученик записывал голосовое сообщение, а потом учитель с помощью этого же бота эти сообщения прослушивал и ставил оценку. Больше всего интересует вопрос как в виде сущности сохранить это голосовое сообщение в базу данных ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Представим ситуацию, что пользователь A отправил голосовое сообщение, а Вам необходимо сделать так, чтобы пользователь Б смог его увидеть и без лишней мороки. Делайте для этого следующие:

1. Ваш обработчик (функция с хендлером диспетчера или роутера, в зависимости от предпочтений и версии aiogram), получив голосовое сообщение, должен достать ID сообщения (message.message_id):

```
# псевдокод, aiogram 3.x

from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.types import Message

something_router = Router()

# предположим, у Вас реализована машина состояний и Вы получаете сообщение с голосовым по конкретному состоянию (State()). Назовем его "send_voice" из класса состояний VoicesStates

@something_router.message(VoicesStates.send_voice, F.content_type == 'voice')
async def get_voice_by_user(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
   voice_message_id = message.message_id
   # тут вызываете функцию записи ID сообщения в базу данных.
```

2. Помещаем в таблицу "voices" значение voice_message_id. К примеру, у Вас будет еще колонка is_verified, которая изначально при инкрементировании voice_message_id в таблицу будет иметь значение False.
3. Когда Ваш условный учитель прописывает условную команду /check_voices (или нажимают на Inline кнопку в админ панели, как удобно), Вы достаете все voice_message_id, помещаете в FSM Storage, и начинаете очередью пересылать сообщения учителю по их ID. Метод bot.send_message имеет опциональное поле reply_to_message_id, в которое уже передаете этот ID.

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрите вариант сохранения message_id голосового сообщения, а при необходимости прослушивания - пересылайте это сообщение учителю. Это будет достаточно просто и корректно.

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, сможете показать пример? 
А то с blob делать не хочется,  а ваш вариант меня заинтересовал

Comment: Сделаю отдельным ответом